# Tool for comparision and generate report

Tags: comparison

I'm lookig for a tool / program where I can generate report say with the information like  lines added,modified,deleted. I'm not looking for araxis merge or diff merge kind of tools , instead the tools that can generate report for me in html /text format.  A **Non '.EXE'** kind of tool is appreciable , since I have software restrictions. Yes I still use tools in exectuable jar, bat etc.. kind

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a windows computer you have `fc.exe` which is a builtin dos app.

```
FC [/A] [/C] [/L] [/LBn] [/N] [/OFF[LINE]] [/T] [/U] [/W] [/nnnn]
   [drive1:][path1]filename1 [drive2:][path2]filename2
FC /B [drive1:][path1]filename1 [drive2:][path2]filename2

  /A         Displays only first and last lines for each set of differences.
  /B         Performs a binary comparison.
  /C         Disregards the case of letters.
  /L         Compares files as ASCII text.
  /LBn       Sets the maximum consecutive mismatches to the specified
             number of lines.
  /N         Displays the line numbers on an ASCII comparison.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  /T         Does not expand tabs to spaces.
  /U         Compare files as UNICODE text files.
  /W         Compresses white space (tabs and spaces) for comparison.
  /nnnn      Specifies the number of consecutive lines that must match
             after a mismatch.
  [drive1:][path1]filename1
             Specifies the first file or set of files to compare.
  [drive2:][path2]filename2
             Specifies the second file or set of files to compare.
```

Maybe it could work?

Comment: Will it do directory comparision ?

Comment: I don't think so. But not beeing able to install additional software limits your choices... You could code something yourself...